# Toaster (ngx-toastr) top-center alignment doesn't have top margin

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ngx-toastr

I'm using the [ngx-toastr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr) library. I'm launching a message positioned at the top-center of the screen like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {

    constructor(private toastrService: ToastrService) { }

    showErrorMessage(message: string) {
         this.toastrService.error(message, undefined, {
              positionClass: 'toast-top-center'
         });
    }
}
```

The problem is that the toast is being shown without any margin on the top:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if I think that this is a design problem, I found out in [here](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues/579) and workaround. You just need to put the following in your main .css or.scss:

```
.toast-top-center {
    top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this in **style.css**

```
.toast {
    margin-top: 45px !important;
}
```